# Running a Window on its own Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am working on an excel add in where it takes a very long time to create the excel sheet. Because of this I am running a progress window (Winform) on its own Thread to notify the user what is going on. I am wondering if I am launch and closing the thread correctly and if I can use something better to create a thread like a task or something else. This is my code

```
   private static Thread tPrgBarfrm;
   private static frmProgressBar frmProgBar;

   //Launching the window
   (tPrgBarfrm = new Thread(() => System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new frmProgressBar()))).Start();//working

   //Update the label in the form
   frmProgBar.UpdateStatusMessage("Completed Calc Sheet");

  //Closing
  tPrgBarfrm.Abort();
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Thread.Abort`, instead you should close the window by calling `Close` on it. This will make `Application.Run` exit and thus the thread will terminate normally.

Comment: Creating a form object on a worker thread is considerable rocket science.  There are a bunch of controls that you cannot use.  Only do this if you understand how to do [this kind of debugging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged/).  You don't have any decent workarounds, Excel itself forces its methods to run on its main thread and there is nothing you can do to make it not do so.   You need to consider doing this without a form and without Excel, use an OpenXML library like ClosedXml.

Comment: @HansPassant It seems that problem only crops up if you're not pumping messages on the thread that owns the window, but would that apply to this situation?

Comment: No, Application.Run or ShowDialog is enough to trigger SystemEvents trouble.  And besides, it is far more convoluted than that.  Excel only exposes apartment-threaded COM objects in its object model, they automatically do the equivalent of Control.Invoke() when used from a worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that is directly wrong with your code is that you're using `Thread.Abort` to close the form by killing off the thread that is hosting it.

**Don't do that!**

There might be situations where `Thread.Abort` is the **only** option, and you **need to kill that thread**, but this method is there for the framework and abnormal exceptional out-there situations.

If you're designing new code where you should be able to close/terminate/exit/kill a subtask/thread, **never, ever** use `Thread.Abort`.

Instead work together with that task/thread and kindly ask it to terminate, upon which the task/thread will do that, by itself, correctly.

So how do you do that here?

**Close the form.**

The message loop code in `Application.Run` will then terminate correctly and the thread will exit normally.

So instead of keeping a reference to the thread, keep one to the form and do this:

```
frmPrgBar.Invoke(frmPrgBar.Close);
```

That is the right thing to do, and it will make all parties involved able to close down and terminate in an orderly fashion.

If you have prevented the form from being closed, you need to add in a way for you to un-prevent that when it becomes time actually to close it, a simple `bool` variable will help you with that.